# Exchange server spam filtering/security

Tags: exchange-2010

We are in the process of implementing Exchange 2010 for 60 users. I would like to know what others are using for spam filtering/email security for Exchange. I am looking at two options:   Microsoft Threat Management Gateway (TMG)  or  Symantec Bright mail Gateway.  If you are using the same or any other options please share your feedback/comments..

Thank you in  advance for any replies…

Regards,
Hemal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TMG used for SMTP is about border/connection protection and has no spam filtering (without 3rd party add-ins).

Built in spam protection is decent but for all my installs I recommend Forefront Protection 2010 for Exchange which does all the spam and AV filtering needs.  http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/protection-for-exchange/en/us/default.aspx

Rather then Forefront onsite you can also outsource it to Microsoft http://www.microsoft.com/online/exchange-email-filtering.aspx

For connection protection I recommend using built-in Edge role on a separate box, or your previously mentioned TMG in front of the hub (i.e. you don't need both edge and TMG)... but in your smaller scenario, TMG is likely an unnecessary expense unless you also plan to go SharePoint, Lync, and go "all in" with the Microsoft products... that's where TMG really shines.

But to that point, I would defiantly recommend (but not require) putting something in front of the hub role, be it either Forefront hosted (you block all IP's but Microsoft's at your FW), or TMG, or edge role, or Google's Postini like KCotreau which I've also used.

Let us know what you go with and why.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Bret. Now I will have to find the best option. Will definitely post it here which way we are going.. Thank you again..

Answer (score 3):

Considering the cost is almost a wash compared to local software, here is something to consider:

Get Google's Postini service: It works very well in my experience. First, you get all the SPAM and virus filtering you need both inbound and outbound. Second, if you do not have a second mail server, it gives you 4 MX records, so if your server goes down, when it comes back up, all the mail gets delivered, and nothing was lost. Lastly, after you have it set up, you can set your firewall to ONLY accept incoming SMTP port 25 traffic from Google's servers, so you face less chances of being attacked by spammers trying to somehow find a hole in your server to relay through.

I would also recommend that you use a reseller rather than going directly to Google, if possible. If you have any setup issues, they are more accessible, and probably know the product well.

Comment: We are getting ready to test Postini.  The cost is negligible vs the cost of local mgmt and users can be given access to release false positives.

Comment: Thank you buddies for reply. I will also look this option.. Am glad post the question. Got so many ideas... Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

We use a [Mailcleaner](http://forum.mailcleaner.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1002) smarthost in our DMZ and it works quite well.  It's a free distro that bundles a bunch of good open source tools (Exim, SpamAssassin, ClamAV, Razor, Pyzor etc) and puts a very friendly web-based management tool on it.  We migrated from Exchange to Zimbra for our mail server a while back, but using Mailcleaner as a mail gateway  has worked extremely well for both.

Technically the current version is still labeled as 'beta 3', but it has been at that stage for over a year and is stable and works well.

As a complete distro, it requires a separate box or VM, but we've been running it happily as a KVM guest for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I've loved our [Barracuda SPAM Filter](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/spam_features.php) that we've had for the best several years.  It's a separate appliance, so they're a high up-front cost, but it's worked very well and been very reliable.